# gcc: readline/libreadline.a: No such file or directory gcc: readline/libhistory.a: No such file or directory

Tags: python, compiling, readline, sles

I am trying to install `python readline 6.2.4.1` package on **SLES 11 SP3** but I am getting the following error:

```
gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -DHAVE_RL_CALLBACK -DHAVE_RL_CATCH_SIGNAL -DHAVE_RL_COMPLETION_APPEND_CHARACTER -DHAVE_RL_COMPLETION_DISPLAY_MATCHES_HOOK -DHAVE_RL_COMPLETION_MATCHES -DHAVE_RL_COMPLETION_SUPPRESS_APPEND -DHAVE_RL_PRE_INPUT_HOOK -I. -I/usr/local/include/python2.7 -c Modules/2.x/readline.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/Modules/2.x/readline.o -Wno-strict-prototypes
gcc -pthread -shared build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/Modules/2.x/readline.o readline/libreadline.a readline/libhistory.a -lncurses -o build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/readline.so
gcc: readline/libreadline.a: No such file or directory
gcc: readline/libhistory.a: No such file or directory
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

How do I solve this?

Comment: Unless I'm looking at the [wrong page](https://pypi.org/project/readline/) it seems that this module was deprecated over six years ago.

Comment: @roaima, thanks but I get the same error when I try to install gnureadline. And now the python command line interface shows this,                                 
Python 2.7.16 (default, Aug  5 2019, 09:06:31) 
[GCC 4.3.4 [gcc-4_3-branch revision 152973]] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/etc/pythonstart", line 7, in <module>
    import readline
  File "readline.py", line 1, in <module>
    from gnureadline import *
ImportError: No module named gnureadline

Comment: Did you read the instructions at https://pypi.org/project/gnureadline/ for installing the updated module? Specifically, "_First… STOP_" and "_Consider this: do you really need this package in 2019?_"

Comment: What is the URL of the source code you are trying to compile?

Comment: @roaima, Yes, I understand but this is needed for another module.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick, I downloaded the tarbal from https://pypi.org/project/readline/#files

Comment: What errors did you get when creating `libreadline.a` and `libhistory.a`? They will need addressing, because until you successfully build those two libraries you're not going to be able to use them.

Comment: Did you use `build.sh` to build the package or something else?